# How can I reference all the camera's properties more easily?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class OnGameLoading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineFreeLook standUpCamera;
    public CinemachineFreeLook closeLookCamera;
    public CinemachineFreeLook gamePlayCamera;

    void Update()
    {
        // When starting a new game
        if (sceneName == "Game" && 
            MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == false && newGameStart == false)
        {
            ThirdPersonUserControl.stop = true;

            standUpCamera.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
            standUpCamera.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;

            closeLookCamera.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
            closeLookCamera.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;

            gamePlayCamera.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
            gamePlayCamera.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something easier to access the properties? This way it's working, but isn't it too much code to write or is it fine this way?

Comment: What about a `CinemachineFreeLook[]` and iterate over them all? Also why doing that each and every frame? Wouldn't it be enough to do this **once** when the scene is loaded?

Comment: About the array, I could do it with array or list but then it will be a bit harder to identify each camera.  That's why I did a variable to each camera with a name.  for doing in the Update I will set the flag newGameStart to true later so it will do it all only once but you right I can do it once in the Start.

Comment: You can have individual fields to identify each camera and still add them all to an array ... but if you only need it once anyway then why bother? ;)

Comment: Also you could work with an dictionary so you have a key value pair with a string and the camera so you would be able to identify each very easly.

Answer (score 1):

I use the advice of 'derHugo, At Least Vision'
Use a dictionary and in this specific use case why not use a method?

```
public class OnGameLoading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineFreeLook standUpCamera;
    public CinemachineFreeLook closeLookCamera;
    public CinemachineFreeLook gamePlayCamera;

    public Dictionary<CinemachineCameraType, CinemachineFreeLook> cinemachineFreeLookCameras = new Dictionary<CinemachineCameraType, CinemachineFreeLook>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        cinemachineFreeLookCameras.Add(CinemachineCameraType.standUpCamera, standUpCamera);
        cinemachineFreeLookCameras.Add(CinemachineCameraType.closeLookCamera, closeLookCamera);
        cinemachineFreeLookCameras.Add(CinemachineCameraType.gamePlayCamera, gamePlayCamera);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // When starting a new game
        if (sceneName == "Game" && MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == false && newGameStart == false)
        {
            ThirdPersonUserControl.stop = true;

            standUpCamera.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
            standUpCamera.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;

            closeLookCamera.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
            closeLookCamera.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;

            gamePlayCamera.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
            gamePlayCamera.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;

            // Dictionary foreach
            foreach (var item in cinemachineFreeLookCameras.Values)
            {
                item.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
                item.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
            }

            // Dictionary for loop
            for (int i = 0; i < cinemachineFreeLookCameras.Count; i++)
            {
                cinemachineFreeLookCameras.ElementAt(i).Value.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0; 
                cinemachineFreeLookCameras.ElementAt(i).Value.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0; 
            }

            // Method
            SetFreeLookCameraAxisMaxSpeed(standUpCamera,0,0);
            SetFreeLookCameraAxisMaxSpeed(closeLookCamera, 0,0);
            SetFreeLookCameraAxisMaxSpeed(gamePlayCamera, 0,0);
        }
    }

    public void SetFreeLookCameraAxisMaxSpeed(CinemachineFreeLook camera,float x,float y)
    {
        camera.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = x;
        camera.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = y;
    }
}

public enum CinemachineCameraType
{
    standUpCamera,
    closeLookCamera,
    gamePlayCamera
}
```